# jquery validation: get remote validation running again without changing the value of concerned field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I hava a remote validator setup like so

```
remote: {
  type: "POST",
  url: "/some/url",
  data: {
    value: function() {
      return $("#field").val();
    },
    bypass: function() {
      if ($("input:radio[name=toggleBypass]:checked").val() == "yes"){
        return "yes";
      }
      return "no";
    }
  }
}
```

If bypass is "yes", the ajax always returns true.

It works on blur and on submit, but if I reset the radio button values then submit, it doesn't revalidate.

For example,

1. Set toggleBypass to "yes"
2. Set field to an invalid value
3. Run $("form").validate().element("#field"). Since bypass is "yes", it passes.
4. Set toggleBypass to "no"
5. Run $("form").validate().element("#field"). It passes, because the remote didnt resubmit.

Any ideas how I can get it to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at line 897 in jquery.validate.js, you'll see an optimization:

`if ( previous.old !== value ) {`

This line prevents a new validation if the field's value hasn't changed. And since you're using `validate().element()`, it only checks that field, not the whole form, so it doesn't detect the change in toggleBypass.

Either remove this check from the jquery.validate source, or check the whole form, not just that field.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try this tomorrow when I get back to work.